# How Dart Upcasts automatically if I use 'is' keyword in the if statement

Tags: dart

These are my classes,

```
class Animal{
  Animal();
}
class Mammal extends Animal{
  String name;
  Mammal(this.name):super();
}
```

Inside my main method,

```
main() {
    Animal dog = new Mammal("Tommy");
    if(dog is Mammal)
        print(dog.name); //prints "Tommy"
}
```

My dog object has the type Animal, how it can expose Mammal's property "name"? Dartpad is itself auto-suggesting me to use 'name' property.

Will, it upcast from Animal type to Mammal for me, because I'm certain that the dog object is a Mammal, once it enters that if statement. But how it works behind the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're describing is called "type promotion", and it only occurs in places that the compiler can *prove* that is it valid.

For example:

- function parameters:

```dart
void function(Animal animal) {
  if (animal is Mammal) {
    // animal now has a static type of Mammal
    print(animal.name); // safe to access Mammal-only fields
  }
}
```

- local variables:

```dart
void function() {
  Animal animal = Mammal('name');
  if (animal is Mammal) {
    // animal now has a static type of Mammal
  }
}
```

However, it does not work for:

- top level fields

```dart
Animal animal = Mammal('name');

void function() {
  if (animal is Mammal) {
    // animal still has static type Animal
  }
}
```

- or instance fields

```dart
class Foo {
  Animal animal;

  void function() {
    if (animal is Animal) {
      // animal still has a static type of Animal
    }
  }
}
```

This is because of Dart's getter syntax. In Dart, you can define getters using the following syntax:

```dart
Foo get foo {
  return makeSomeFoo();
}
```

In fact, although most people think "getters are functions that look like fields", it is actually the opposite: fields automatically generate corresponding getters. This means that type promotion can't be used anywhere a field access could conceptually be a getter.

Since local variables and function parameters have no notion of "overriding getters", they are safe.

However, imagine the following top level getter:

```dart
Animal get animal {
  if (Random().nextBool()) return Mammal('name');
  else return Reptile('name');
}
```

Just because the first call to `animal` has returned a `Mammal`, doesn't mean subsequent calls always will, so it is not safe to assume that `animal` is now a `Mammal`.

Similar logic applies to classes, with the added complication that getters can override fields.

Note, you can easily get around the issue with instance members and top level getters by using a local variable:

```dart
Animal get animal => // some implementation

void function() {
  final _animal = animal;
  if (_animal is Animal) {
    print(_animal.name);  // totally safe
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, it is called smart casting. Dart can do the casting automatically for local variables if it's inside a conditional statement that guarantees the type of the variable.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen it called "smart casting" in official Dart documentation.  It's normally called type promotion.  (There are some other cases where it won't happen; see https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons).